# useEffect in nextjs always set serverSideProps as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, fetch, next-auth

I have tried every solution in the internet, but still its always undefined.

I am trying to fetch wishlist from user table, on the basis of email.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import axios from 'axios';
import { QUERIES_SHOE, WEIGHTS_SHOE } from '../constants';

const Wishlist = ({ products, email, wishlist }) => {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession()
    const [wishlistProducts, setWishlistProducts] = useState([]);

    const [emails, setEmails] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      if(!email){
        return; // if token doesn't exist yet, don't call the api
      } else { 
        const findLang = async() => {
          const ress = await axios.get(buildUrl('/api/users/wishlist'), {
            email
          });
          const data = await ress.rows?.[0];
          setWishlistProducts(data);
        };
        findLang();
      }
      
    }, [email]);

    console.log('wish', wishlist)


  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {wishlistProducts?
        <>
          {wishlistProducts?.map((wish) => {
            <label>{wish}</label>
          })}
        </>
      : null
      }
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const res = await axios.get(buildUrl('/api/products'))
    const session = await getSession({ req: context.req });
    if (!session) {
      return {
       //redirect to login
      };
    }
    var email = session?.user?.user?.email;
    console.log(email)
  const ress = await axios.get(buildUrl('/api/users/wishlist'));
    return {
        props: {
            products: res.data,
            wishlist: ress.data,
            email,
        }
    }
}
export default Wishlist;
```

As you can see in the above code. The email is passsed as serverSideProps. When I try to fetch, the api always receives undefined email.

Comment: in the component, what `console.log(email)`  logs

Comment: its email john@gmail.com

Comment: What variable is `undefined` then?